# Организовать скачивание по URL, отображая картинки и текст. Android, java.

Tags: android, java

В общем, задача следующая: написать Android приложение, которое ведет скачивание по URL и отображает результат. Требования к результату: должны отображаться текст и картинки. Вся фишка в том, что нужно как-то распарсить Интернет поток, чтобы можно было извлечь оттуда текст и картинки. Т.е. вариант типа этого WebView webView.loadUrl(url.toString()); - не катит. Какими методами можно распарсить Интернет поток для извлечения необходимого контента?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться  [HTML Cleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/).

Вот [статья с хабра с подробным руководством](http://habrahabr.ru/post/115127/).

Кратко: подключаем библиотеку в проект (как - описано по ссылке выше), загружаем страницу с помощью объекта HTMLCleaner, с помощью его методов "вытаскиваем" нужную нам инфу (текст, ссылки на картинки) с загруженной страницы, после текст пихаем в TextView, картинки же грузим отдельно и пихаем в ImageView.

Ещё есть JSOUP